# How would I call a method in a Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

So I have a method and what it does is it gets the processor name of my PC basically..

Now how would I do the same thing if I were to do it in a Console Application.

This is what I tried but it didnt print out anything

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
using System.Management;

namespace testereeee
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello World");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private string GetProcessorName()
        {
            string ProcessorName = "";
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos
            = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
                ProcessorName = mo["Name"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(ProcessorName.ToString());
            return ProcessorName;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make your `GetProcessorName` method static, then call it from the `Main` method.

Comment: Well GetProcessorName() is never called and it needs to be a static method. And is hello world atleast present?

Comment: So " static string " ?
and yes hello world is presented.

Comment: That worked! Thanks guys!

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't print anything because it was never called, update your code to be like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
using System.Management;

namespace testereeee
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello World");
            GetProcessorName()

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string GetProcessorName()
        {
            string ProcessorName = "";
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos
            = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
                ProcessorName = mo["Name"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(ProcessorName.ToString());
            return ProcessorName;
        }        
    }
}
```